# Is it possible to create a button pointing downward (image included) with only CSS?

Tags: css

I would like to create this using only CSS. Is this possible? If so, can you guys help me out?

[image]

Comment: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: @Pete That's an awesome site but I can't get the arrows to shorten in height like the image in my post.

Comment: This might also be interesting: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: The reference given by @Wipster has your answer (more or less).  Look at the chevron construction, you need to square off the top part and make it flat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fairly easy with borders and a pseudo element:

```
<a href="#" id="button">ALL</a>

#button::after {
    content: "";
    border: 64px solid transparent;
    border-top: 12px solid orange;
    position: absolute;
    top: 29px;
    left: 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QbRUX/1/)

Comment: Perfect! Is there any way to get this working in the latest IE by any chance? :)

Comment: Should work fine in IE8+. You may have to tweak positioning etc.

Comment: @3rror404 Ah, yes you're correct. I changed `a` to `button` and that's why it wasn't working in IE. But no worries, everything is fine now. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to experiment with this basic button:

```
.btn {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
}
.btn-arrow {
    position: relative;
    background: coral;
}
.btn-arrow:after {
    border: solid transparent;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    border-top-color: coral;
    border-width: 16px 50px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/tNjCb/1/

Answer (score 2):

how about something like the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/WDCu3/

```
<div id="test">Testing</div>
<div id="arrow"></div>

#test {background-color:red; width:100px;}
div {text-align:center;}

#arrow {
    border-top: 15px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width:0;
}
```